# How to switch tabs in iTerm2 on a Mac using SHIFT-arrow keys, _not_ CTRL-arrow keys

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, iterm2, iterm

Pretty much what the title says...

My work flow in iTerm2 (just upgraded to 3.4.10 to see if that fixed the problem; no, it did not) let me hit Shift-Left Arrow to move to the previous tab and Shift-Right Arrow to switch to the next tab.

That recently stopped working and I can't get it back. ;-( I must now use Ctrl-arrow keys which is not ergonomic by any reach.

I have changed the key prefs in Preferences -> Keys and in individual profiles. I have restarted iTerm2 after doing so. I've made no changes to the OS (.inputrc, etc.)

As I said, this was part of my workflow and now it isn't.

N.B. I do NOT want to highlight a previous/next word; I do NOT want to edit in Vim/Emacs; I do NOT want to move tabs around via keyboard...

I want to switch between iTerm2 tabs using Shift-arrow keys.

Anyone know the secret?

Answer (score 3):

In iTerm2, go `Preferences`/`Keys`/`Key Bindings` and remap the bindings for `Previous Tab` and `Next Tab` to your liking.

**Note**: watch out for potential conflicts with existing bindings. If you do get conflict warnings, go `Preferences`/`Profiles`/`Keys`/`Key Mappings` for each profile and remove the conflicting mapping.

Comment: Nope. Doesn't work. The key stroke Sh-LKey still prints ;2D just like it did before the remapping. (I can't have paragraphs in this comment?!) I _do_ get a warning about a profile overriding it, but I've only got two profiles and I can't find any place where "Previous Tab" is re-mapped.

Comment: Have a look at my amended answer.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it still didn't work. So I extended the idea and made the keys do the same thing in both profile and globally(?). NOW it does what I want, at least on the laptop; next to test it with the mech keyboard. (No paragraphs? Really?) Thanks for the inspiration and guidance.